# Discord.js client.channel.cache.get().send() is not a Function

Tags: discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'token';

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.channels.cache.get('channelid').send('Test');
});

client.login(token);
```

Whenever I try to run this, it always says: "(node:20284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.channels.cache.get(...).send is not a function"

Comment: I should mention that I am trying to make the bot send a message on startup so I can check to see if it works in the first place, because I kept getting errors before about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution, but rather a workaround. This problem is caused probably because the channels ain't being stored on the ChannelManager cache, I don't know the solution to this (I can edit the answer if somebody does), but you could fetch the channel directly using the promise based `ChannelManager.fetch(id: string)`, like that:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', async function() {
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch('channelId');

  channel.send('message');
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: it says await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes, exactly, just write async before your handler function. So, ```() => {``` should become ```async () => {``` and then you can use await.